# How to go to the non source map code in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Let's say I am in my source map file in chrome and I'd like to see that specific function inthe non source map version.

Just temporally, not to disable the source map completely.

I want to know what my code looks like. I know I can open the emitted file, but I'd like a quick thing from dev tools

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate from the minified file to the original source by setting a breakpoint. It's not ideal, as it may pause and you might not want to pause.

I cannot find a way to navigate the other direction, from the original source to the minified file.